# Upload to S3 from Django admin

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got my django app setup to use S3 using `storages` and `boto`. Using `collectstatic`, I was able to move my static assets to S3. However, I need to also store the image files uploaded from Django Admin to S3.

I used the django-s3direct package from [here](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct). I was able to set it up correctly and the upload seems to work. However, on loading the template, the uploaded image is not served.

My Settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'ACCESS_KEY'

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'SECRET_KEY'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucketname'

S3DIRECT_ENDPOINT = 's3.amazonaws.com'  # http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region
S3DIRECT_DIR = 's3direct'  # (optional, default is 's3direct', location within the bucket to upload files)
S3DIRECT_UNIQUE_RENAME = False # (optional, default is 'False', gives the uploaded file a unique filename)
```

Models.py:

```
class BannerAds(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20)
    image = S3DirectField(upload_to='s3direct')
```

Comment: In your template, use Inspect Element to find out what the page is trying to load for the image. How does that compare to the actual path to the image in your S3 bucket?

Comment: It's using the old path which was `/dynamic/img`.

Comment: have you set `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`?

Comment: Aah, I haven't. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set up media files, which include uploades.

There are several ways to do this, I used [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Among other things, you have to change your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
] + + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and yes you have to add a setting for `MEDIA_ROOT` as well.

But the big thing is media files, google that and you'll be on your way.